# i wanted to make calculator using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a calculator I wanted to take the number and the operation from the input and onclick to display the result  in another input field. Just to test if the button work console.log(num1+num2) but  I see no result in the console log. and i also what to know how i can pass my operation from the input

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
var oper = document.getElementById("oper").value;
var cal = document.getElementById("cal").value;
var res = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var calculatorBtn = document.getElementById("calculator");
const form = document.querySelector("formCal");

function calculate() {
  console.log(num1 + num2);
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <form action="" id="formCal">

    <div class="calculator">
      <div class="box">
        <label for="num1">Number 1</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="num1" id="num1">
      </div>
      <div class="box">

        <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="num2" id="num2">
      </div>
      <div class="box">

        <label for="oper">operation</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="oper" id="oper">
      </div>
      <div class="box">

        <label for="res">Result</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="res" id="res">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <input type="button" id="cal" value="calculator" placeholder="calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: very similar to this question, you’ll see how to achieve the calculation by using `eval()` there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373130/unexpected-identifier-at-htmlbuttonelement-anonymous

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!-- Create a simple Program to build the Calculator in JavaScript using with HTML and CSS web languages. -->  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang = "en">  
<head>  
<title> JavaScript Calculator </title>  
  
<style>  
h1 {  
    text-align: center;  
    padding: 23px;  
    background-color: skyblue;  
    color: white;  
    }  
  
#clear{  
width: 270px;  
border: 3px solid gray;  
    border-radius: 3px;  
    padding: 20px;  
    background-color: red;  
}  
  
.formstyle  
{  
width: 300px;  
height: 530px;  
margin: auto;  
border: 3px solid skyblue;  
border-radius: 5px;  
padding: 20px;  
}  
  
  
  
input  
{  
width: 20px;  
background-color: green;  
color: white;  
border: 3px solid gray;  
    border-radius: 5px;  
    padding: 26px;  
    margin: 5px;  
    font-size: 15px;  
}  
  
  
#calc{  
width: 250px;  
border: 5px solid black;  
    border-radius: 3px;  
    padding: 20px;  
    margin: auto;  
}  
  
</style>  
  
</head>  
<body>  
<h1> Calculator Program in JavaScript </h1>  
<div class= "formstyle">  
<form name = "form1">  
      
    <!-- This input box shows the button pressed by the user in calculator. -->  
  <input id = "calc" type ="text" name = "answer"> <br> <br>  
  <!-- Display the calculator button on the screen. -->  
  <!-- onclick() function display the number prsses by the user. -->  
  <input type = "button" value = "1" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '1' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "2" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '2' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "3" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '3' ">  
   <input type = "button" value = "+" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '+' ">  
  <br> <br>  
    
  <input type = "button" value = "4" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '4' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "5" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '5' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "6" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '6' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "-" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '-' ">  
  <br> <br>  
    
  <input type = "button" value = "7" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '7' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "8" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '8' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "9" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '9' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "*" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '*' ">  
  <br> <br>  
    
    
  <input type = "button" value = "/" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '/' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "0" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '0' ">  
    <input type = "button" value = "." onclick = "form1.answer.value += '.' ">  
    <!-- When we click on the '=' button, the onclick() shows the sum results on the calculator screen. -->  
  <input type = "button" value = "=" onclick = "form1.answer.value = eval(form1.answer.value) ">  
  <br>   
  <!-- Display the Cancel button and erase all data entered by the user. -->  
  <input type = "button" value = "Clear All" onclick = "form1.answer.value = ' ' " id= "clear" >  
  <br>   
    
</form>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the value inside your function. Otherwise this won't get triggered again.

```js
function calculate(){
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    console.log(num1+num2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div class="root">
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
       <form action="" id="formCal">

            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="num1">Number 1</label>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="num1" id="num1">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
    
                    <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="num2" id="num2">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
    
                    <label for="oper">operation</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="oper" id="oper">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    
                    <label for="res">Result</label>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="res" id="res">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <input type="button" id="cal" value="calculator" placeholder="calculate" onclick="calculate()"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the code doesn't update the variables, so it's just set to the value and the value is null at that time its set,I fixed it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div class="root">
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
       <form action="" id="formCal">

            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="num1">Number 1</label>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="num1" id="num1">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
    
                    <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="num2" id="num2">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
    
                    <label for="oper">operation</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="oper" id="oper">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    
                    <label for="res">Result</label>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="res" id="res">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <input type="button" id="cal" value="calculator" placeholder="calculate" onclick="calculate()"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        
    </div>
    <headers>
        <script >
            var num1 =document.getElementById("num1").value;
            var num2= document.getElementById("num2").value ;
            var oper=document.getElementById("oper").value ;
            var cal=document.getElementById("cal") ;
            var res=document.getElementById("num1").value ;
            var calculatorBtn =document.getElementById("calculator");
            const form = document.querySelector("formCal");
            function calculate(){
                var num1 = new Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
                var num2 = new Number(document.getElementById("num2").value) ;
                var res = document.getElementById("res")
                switch(document.getElementById("oper").value)
                {
                    case "+":
                        res.value = num1 + num2;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        res.value = num1 - num2;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        res.value = num1 * num2;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        res.value = num1/num2;
                        break;
                }
            }
            </script>
    </headers>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- All the JS codes outside the function will get executed immediately once the page starts to load. In your case, you will enter values in text box only after the page gets loaded.
- The num1 and num2 variables will not get assigned at the time you hit on the calculate button as these codes are outside the function.
- Secondly, you should use ParseInt as javascript will consider your values as strings and gives you concatenated result.
- Replace your script as below,

  ```
   /*var oper=document.getElementById("oper").value ;
   var cal=document.getElementById("cal").value ;
   var res=document.getElementById("num1").value ;
   var calculatorBtn =document.getElementById("calculator");
   const form = document.querySelector("formCal");*/

   function calculate(){
   var num1 =document.getElementById("num1").value ;
   var num2= document.getElementById("num2").value ;

   console.log(parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2));
   }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Once you have a string for the calculation, you can run [the `eval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute the calculation as JavaScript code.

Since you are generating a string, you might not need the `parseInt` at all.

Using `eval()` poses a potential security risk, if you publish a site using it. Use it only for your learning experiments.

```
function calculate(){
    const num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    const num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    const oper = document.getElementById("oper").value;
    document.getElementById('res').value = eval(num1 + oper + num2);
}
```